# What breakpoint width to switch to mobile menu?

Tags: mobile, navigation, menu, toggle, hamburger

Sounds like it should have an obvious, clear-cut answer, but I couldn't find much mention of it: When building a website, what breakpoint / width is most ideal to switch from a horizontal tab-style nav menu to a vertical toggle mobile menu, hidden behind a 'hamburger' ☰ icon?

Seeing as I mostly seem to be designing websites with a container width of 1200px, and there aren't many desktop / laptop computer screen sizes below that, I've been getting the mobile menu to kick in at / below that 1200px width, which simplifies my workflow somewhat.

But is it good practice? Is there an audience of device users who would prefer a lower breakpoint? Perhaps iPad users in landscape orientation would prefer a "normal" menu?

I've seen websites that have a collapsible mobile-style menu for all widths, including desktop, so I guess it comes down to the desired UX on a case-by-case basis, however it would be useful to know of any unforeseen considerations.

Comment: at which width your menu still fits the horizontal tab-style.. e.g. as a programmer, I often use my browser in 1/2 of a HD screen => around 950-960px - mobile menu would be OK, horizontal scrolling would not.

Comment: Setting the breakpoint just outside the menu width used to be my approach and think that's one of the reasons I changed direction and started using a standard 1200px breakpoint. There were too many considerations, for example the fact that menus can change size when the client adds items - just one of many which added up, and solved by moving the breakpoint way outward.

Comment: When you say 'vertical toggle mobile menu' are you talking about hiding it behind a hamburger/ menu icon or simply displaying it vertically?

Comment: Yes @Woodwork, I was referring to hiding it behind a hamburger ☰ icon which drops down vertically when clicked. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forget mobile breakpoints, **there's no *phone* and *tablet* sizes** outside marketing. Breakpoints should follow the content, not the screen size.

As a simple example, let's consider the menu:

```
  Home  |  Products  |  Contacts
```

Do you think you should ever provide a *mobile* menu? Do you really want to stick three elements in a hamburger menu? They can probably fit very well on your screen at `>=320px`

On the other hand, there's this menu:

```
 Home  | TVs | Tablets | Notebooks | Printers | Air Conditioners | Routers | Help
```

Which needs to be adjusted much sooner. But at the same time, do you want to show a hamburger at `<1000px` because it doesn't fit on one line?

I would explore other navigation options, like the [Priority+ pattern](https://css-tricks.com/the-priority-navigation-pattern/)

---

As a side note, this applies to all of the site parts. Don't just *switch to the mobile layout* just because you reached `<700px` even if content still fits perfectly the way it is at `400px`. Google Web Fundamentals has a page exactly on this:

> Create breakpoints based on content, never on specific devices, products, or brands.
>
> From: [How to choose breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/how-to-choose-breakpoints)

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the direction of Priority+ Pattern @bfred.it